# Why elements in A and B must be the same for my code?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

```
clc
%clear all
close all
G=1000;
R=0.372;
Rs=0.2;
lamda=300*10^(-9);
I=0.01;
h=6.626*10^(-34);
c=3*10^8;
mun=100;
taun=5*10^(-9);
mup=25;
taup=5*10^(-9);
e=8.854*10^(-12);
alpha=0.473;
We=50*10^(-9);
Wa=5*10^(-9);
ni=1;
%VD=-10:0.01:10;
q=1.602*10^(-19);
n=1.5;
k=1.38*10^(-23);
T=283;
Na=1*10^(14);
VT=((k*T)/q);    %VT=KT/q
G= ((1-R)*(lamda*I))/(h*c);%G=(1-R)?I/hc
syms x
fn=int(1/(mun*taun*((q*Na*(x-Wa))/e)));
syms x
FN=int(exp(-(alpha+fn)),(We+Wa),(We+x)); 
Jn=q*G*alpha*exp(fn)*FN;
x=-10:0.01:10;
JN=subs(Jn);
syms x
fp=int(1/(mup*taup*((q*Na*(x-Wa))/e))); 
syms x
FP=int(exp(-(alpha+fp)),(We+x),We);
Jp=q*G*alpha*exp(fp)*FP;
x=-10:0.01:10; 
JP=subs(Jp);
Jph=JN+JP;
J0=((q*ni*Wa)/(2*sqrt(taun*taup)));
J=zeros(1,2003);
j=1;
J(1,1)=0;
for VL=0:0.001:5
    Jpart=J0*(exp(VL-(J(j,1)*Rs)/(n*VT)))-1;
    J(j+1)=-Jph+Jpart; 
    VL1(j+1)=VL; 
    j=j+1;
    plot(VL1(j),J(j,1), 'r')
    hold on
    grid on   
end
```

In this code I am getting error:

In an assignment  A(:) = B, the number of elements in A and B must be the same.

Error in Code2 (line 49)
    J(j+1)=-Jph+Jpart;

I want to get output like the following figure:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ocpO.jpg)

there is no output. Please anyone help me...

Comment: Not "elements must be the same" but "*number* of elements must be the same".  Or in other words `size(J(j+1))` must be the same as `size(-Jhp+Jpart)`. You can not put more things in a variable than the space it has.

Answer (score 0):

Checking your model is your homework, and is filled with errors of every kind. But the code solely, is now functional:

```
%%
clc
%clear all
close all
G=1000;
R=0.372;
Rs=0.2;
lamda=300*10^(-9);
I=0.01;
h=6.626*10^(-34);
c=3*10^8;
mun=100;
taun=5*10^(-9);
mup=25;
taup=5*10^(-9);
e=8.854*10^(-12);
alpha=0.473;
We=50*10^(-9);
Wa=5*10^(-9);
ni=1;
%VD=-10:0.01:10;
q=1.602*10^(-19);
n=1.5;
k=1.38*10^(-23);
T=283;
Na=1*10^(14);
VT=((k*T)/q);    %VT=KT/q
G= ((1-R)*(lamda*I))/(h*c);%G=(1-R)?I/hc
%%
syms x
fn=int(1/(mun*taun*((q*Na*(x-Wa))/e)));
FN=int(exp(-(alpha+fn)),(We+Wa),(We+x)); 
Jn=q*G*alpha*exp(fn)*FN;
fp=int(1/(mup*taup*((q*Na*(x-Wa))/e))); 
FP=int(exp(-(alpha+fp)),(We+x),We);
Jp=q*G*alpha*exp(fp)*FP
%% 
nx=2001;
x=(-10:20/(nx-1):10)'; 
VL=(0:5/(nx-1):5)';
JN=eval(Jn);
JP=eval(subs(Jp));
Jph=JN+JP;
J0=((q*ni*Wa)/(2*sqrt(taun*taup)));
%%
J(1,1)=0;
for j=2:nx
    j
    Jpart(j,1)=J0*(exp(VL(j,1)-(J(j-1,1)*Rs)/(n*VT)))-1;
    J(j,1)=-Jph(j,1)+Jpart(j,1); 
    plot(VL(1:j,1),real(J(1:j,1)));
end
```